# Cosa significa "torcida"?

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary

La maggior parte dei dizionari cui ho fatto riferimento dà un significato afferente alla tifoseria sportiva. Tuttavia, nei contesti in cui ho visto l'uso di questa parola, mi sembra piuttosto un altro il significato inteso.

> è un programma intriso di *torcida* indefessa e inesausta.
>
> Si avverte davvero la *torcida* inesausta.
>
> [di un'immagine] È già *torcida*

Faccio notare che potrebbe appartenere a qualche dialettica toscana.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In realtà credo che la definizione che hai trovato sia quella corretta (derivante dal portoghese brasiliano). Prendo il significato da http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/T/torcida.php:

> gerg. Il tifo sportivo particolarmente pittoresco e chiassoso, tipico del calcio sudamericano || estens. La tifoseria che lo pratica

Se ricordo bene l'espressione "*torcida indefessa e inesausta*" viene usata dal giornalista Andrea Scanzi in modo sarcastico a indicare qualcosa per cui non c'è per nulla per cui esaltarsi.

Comment: È la stessa definizione perché è lo stesso dizionario (monolingue Hoepli) su entrambi i siti... ;-) Comunque *torcida* viene dal portoghese brasiliano (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/torcida e https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torcida_organizada).

Comment: @DaG grazie per la precisazione! Modifico la mia risposta

Comment: Sì Riccardo, viene proprio da Scanzi. Ma negli altri due casi, come va interpretata?

Comment: Una volta capito che “torcida” indica il tifo calcistico scatenato, gli usi ironici o traslati non sono più di stretta pertinenza della linguistica, ma lasciati all'interpretazione di ognuno di noi. Non ci dici quale sia l'immagine di cui viene detto “È già torcida”: se è una curva piena di tifosi, l'uso è letterale; se è una panchina con un tizio addormentato, sarà ironico; se è il parlamento di un paese, ci sarà un intento satirico; se è un cavatappi, sarà un'opera surrealista. E così via.